# JPA: querying an entity with a restriction on inverse one-to-one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a bi-directional one-to-one relation on an entity. I want to query for the inverse side entities where the restriction concerns the said relation. More specifically, I want all of the entities where the one-to-one doesn't map to any relation (i.e. is null).

My entities:

The inverse:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="direct_debit")
@Audited
public class DirectDebit implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="debit", targetEntity = Account.class)
    private Account account;

    ...
    Simple getters and setters for all fields here
    ...

}
```

The owner:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Audited
public abstract class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private String accountId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="debit_id")
    private DirectDebit debit;

    ...
    Simple getters and setters for all fields here
    ...
}
```

My query is an attempt to retrieve all `DirectDebit` instances whose accounts are null. My attempted criteria query:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<DirectDebit> getUnassignedDirectDebits(){

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DirectDebit> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DirectDebit.class);

    Root<DirectDebit> directDebitRoot = query.from(DirectDebit.class);
    query.select(directDebitRoot);

    query.where(criteriaBuilder.isNull(directDebitRoot.get("account")));

    List<DirectDebit> accounts = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    for (DirectDebit account : accounts){
        entityManager.detach(account);
    }

    return accounts;

}
```

However, the query that this generates is not at all what I've expected:

```
select directdebi0_.id as id1_16_ from direct_debit directdebi0_ where directdebi0_.id is null
```

Naturally, this query returns no results.

Am I expecting hibernate/jpa to do something that it cannot (seeing as the query is somewhat odd)? Is there a different way I can do what I'm trying to achieve here?

I'm using Hibernate as the JPA provider, and the database I'm connecting to is MySQL.

Comment: Using oracle by chance?

Comment: Probably should've mentioned this in the original post - it's MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The `CriteriaBuilder.isNull` only work as spected with the owner's entity.

On your case, you can do:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<DirectDebit> getUnassignedDirectDebits(){

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DirectDebit> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(DirectDebit.class);

    Root<DirectDebit> directDebitRoot = query.from(DirectDebit.class);
    query.select(directDebitRoot);


    //Changes ini
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> ids = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Integer.class);
    Root<Account> accountRoot = ids.from(Account.class); 
    Path<Integer> path = accountRoot.get("debit").<Integer>get("id");
    TypedQuery<Integer> idsQuery = entityManager.createQuery(ids.select(path));
    query.where(criteriaBuilder.not(directDebitRoot.in(idsQuery.getResultList())));
    //query.where(criteriaBuilder.isNull(directDebitRoot.get("account")));
    //Changes end


    List<DirectDebit> accounts = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    for (DirectDebit account : accounts){
        entityManager.detach(account);
    }

    return accounts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want can be accomplished by a simple query, I suggest you not use the hibernate criteria API and user HQL/JPQL.

Try this.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
List<DirectDebit> accounts = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT directDebit FROM DirectDebit directDebit WHERE directDebit.account IS NULL").getResultList();
```

Comment: Your suggestion is an equivalent of the criteria query I showed there. Just to be sure I ran it as well, and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: The query that is generated in your example is not equivalent to the HQL i provided. The results should not be the same.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood me - the criteria query, not the SQL query generated from it, is equivalent to the HQL query you showed. The HQL query you suggested generated the exact same SQL query when run.